# Manipulating with rows where data needs to match with a partial string of a column and one other condition

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I need to filter a specific data. In order to do this I need my filter to match two conditions:
1) needs to match a partial string
2) a value of one column needs to be more than 1
the dataset needs to stay exacxtly the same --> I could do this in two steps with grep function but I would get a new dataset only with the data I am looking to change and that I do not want.

my data looks like this:

```
    name                         nr_item    price   content end_nr_item
MINI HVLP Spritzpistole              1      20,16      1      1
LED G4 G9 MR16 GU10                  1      13,09      6      6
Trennscheiben Ø115 Ø125 Ø230         2      12,53      30     60
Trennscheiben Ø115 Ø125 Ø230         2      12,53      1      2
LED G4 G9 MR16 GU10                  3      35,49      20     60
Trennscheiben Ø115 Ø125 Ø230         1      10,18      4      4
```

I wanted to filter the data with the data$name ="Trennscheiben" and that has a data$content > 1

What I have managed to programe so far (it is not ok):

```
for(i in 1:length(data$content)){
  if(data[grep("Trennscheiben", data$name[i]), ] & data$content[i] > 1){
    data$end_nr_item[i] <- data$end_nr_item[i] / 10
  }
}
```

I amstuck at this point... I would appreciate the help.

Comment: `df[grepl('Trennscheiben', df$name) & df$content > 1,]`

Comment: with this comand I filter the data and get another dataset... I do not however get a result in the old dataframe

Comment: @AndražPoje: then set what Sotos wrote to `data`. That is: `data <-  data[grepl('Trennscheiben', data$name) & data$content > 1,]`.

Comment: I do understand that he used different variabales. I am arguing that whit that operation I am geting a subset of the original data and not the computation inside the existing dataset.

Comment: @AndražPoje what do you mean? You are effectively doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an answer added to your data frame then I would suggest adding a logical vector as a new column.

something like:

```
library('stringr')

data$answer_to_my_filter_question <- str_detect(data$name,'Trennscheiben')== TRUE & data$content > 1
```

This will return a logical string with your answer.

You could do the same thing using the mutate() function in the dplyr package:

```
library('dplyr')
library('stringr')

data <- mutate(data, answer_to_my_filter_question = (str_detect(name,'Trennscheiben') == TRUE & content > 1))
```